# Extending sealed class

Tags: windows-runtime, .net-4.5, sealed

I'm developing Windows Store application using javascript. I also have WinRT library for client-server interactions. Client receives from server a custom class `User`, which is sealed, as it's required for classes in WinRT lib. I need to extend `User` object for further use with data binding.

What are best practices for doing it? Is there best way than creating new `UserDataBinding` class and copying all properties from `User`?

Comment: And suggestion for your approach - instead of copy of all propeties - store a instance of user class in your wrapping binding class and expose through get set properties values you need. If your User class is your custom code why cant you just put binding stuff there ?

Comment: @drk sounds like a view model to me..

Comment: Yeah pretty much the same, i didn't see your answer before posting comment

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern and wrapping the User object with a View Model?